# How to customize React Native Paper Switch components for android?

Tags: react-native, material-ui, material-design, react-native-paper, material-design-icons

When I use this code from react native paper I expect the switch component to be exactly look likse the **[Material design 3](https://m3.material.io/components/switch/overview) **switch, but unfortunately it is not and looks like older version, I was curios how to customize this component to looks like the md3[react native paper switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axf09.png)
[Official docs of MD3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8J1p.png)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isSwitchOn, setIsSwitchOn] = React.useState(false);

  const onToggleSwitch = () => setIsSwitchOn(!isSwitchOn);

  return <Switch value={isSwitchOn} onValueChange={onToggleSwitch} />;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

if anyone can help me, much appreciated :)

I could not custmize this comonent to look like md3 design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, React Native Paper doesn't support MD3 for the Switch component

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/3689#issuecomment-1436567611

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/3797

Comment: Can Edit Or customize it since it is not been updated by react native yet?

Comment: No. Try to create your own component using Reanimated & Gesture Handler

Comment: Thank you I'll do some search on internet